# undeclared identifier С++

Tags: c++

packet.h

```
class OutcomingEnterMap : public PacketFactory
{
public:
    int process(Player&);
private:

    MapCharacterBase    _MapCharacterBase;

};
```

packet_pre_world.cpp

```
#include "packet.h"

struct MapCharacterBase  {
    /* ... */
};

int OutcomingEnterMap::proces(connection* d)
{

    _MapCharacterBase = MapCharacterBase{/* ... */}; 

}
```

Ошибка

```
Error   C2065   '_MapCharacterBase': undeclared identifier  EmulatorTop c:\users\ilya\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\emulatortop\threadevents\packet_pre_world.cpp   142
```

Comment: 1) MapCharacterBase   надо предопределить в packet.h. 2) Может это стандарт нового с++, но `= MapCharacterBase{/* ... */};` кажись нельзя так делать.

Comment: нужно просто определение структуры MapCharacterBase перенести с `packet_pre_world.cpp` в `packet.h`.

Comment: Точно определить. Предопределить можно только если указатель на структуру.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "packet.h"

struct MapCharacterBase  {
    /* ... */
};
```

Превращается в

```
class OutcomingEnterMap : public PacketFactory
{
public:
    int process(Player&);
private:

    MapCharacterBase    _MapCharacterBase;   // 1

};

struct MapCharacterBase  {                   // 2
    /* ... */
};
```

Т.е. вы используете `MapCharacterBase` **до** его объявления. Компилятор не понимает в точке 1, что такое `MapCharacterBase`, так как это ему становится понятно только в точке 2.